# Logging in to Stack Overflow doesn't log me in to Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, stack-exchange

EDIT: I accidentally wrote "login screen" instead of "logout screen" in a comment. I just wanted to confirm that the issue still persists.

---

As of today, after I log in to Stack Overflow, I am *not* automatically logged in to other Stack Exchange websites.

## Expected behaviour

After logging to Stack Overflow, I should be automatically logged in to other Stack Exchange websites. (This was the behaviour I observed for last 20 months or so, up until today.)

## My setup

"Vanilla" account - ie. registered with Stack Overflow proper.

Chrome 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) and 59.0.3071.115 (64-bit) - haven't tested on other browsers.

## Steps to reproduce

1. Log in to Stack Overflow.
2. Go to another Stack Exchange website (tested on: Movies, RPG, Meta SE, Puzzling) - notice you're not logged in.
3. Refresh another Stack Exchange website - notice you're still not logged in.
4. Click on "log in" link at the top of the page - notice you're greeted with regular log in screen.
5. Log in using credentials - notice that *now* you're logged in across all Stack Exchange sites.
6. Click on log out on either Stack Overflow or another Stack Exchange website - notice you're logged out on **both** Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites.

I have reproduced this twice so far.

EDIT:

I have tried to log out, and the (previously extensive) list of sites I was about to log out from was now reduced to a single item: Stack Overflow.

[image: surprisingly slim log out screen]

EDIT #2:

Weirdly enough, when I log in to another Stack Exchange site first (this time: Super User), I am automatically logged in when I go to Stack Overflow.

EDIT #3:

Tested this on Firefox 54.0.1 (32-bit). Same behaviour.

Comment: I just went to log out of GIS.SE and the logout screen included multiple sites but it listed sites I don't belong to and left out a few I do have accounts on. Very weird.

Comment: Same thing here. Log into SO, go to any other SE site and I must log in again before I can do anything or get my favorite tags to appear.  Thanks for the tip about logging into the other SE site first and then going to SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Happy Friday.

The fix is rolling out now.

Long story short, we append `<img>` tags to the footer at the end of the auth process to make pixel gif requests to the other domains (that come back with account cookies). The new footer was missing the id attribute.